# C# Windows Form - ToolTip Delay doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I am attempting to incorporate a delay for the ToolTip via OnMouseHover, but it appears to ignore my specified delay (ToolTip is displaying immediately on hover instead of after the delay). I figured this would be a simple change, but there must be something that I'm missing.

I've tried configuring the delay associated with the ToolTip, but that didn't have any effect. I also included just the "DDToolTip.AutomaticDelay = 5000", and removed the other properties but that didn't appear to change anything either.

I've also tried replacing `DDToolTip.Show(strTooltip, this.Parent, pnt, 10000);` with `DDToolTip.SetToolTip(this.Parent, strTooltip, strTooltip);`, but that has caused the tool tip to not appear at all.

```
public DDButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DDToolTip = new ToolTip();
            DDToolTip.InitialDelay = 5000;
            DDToolTip.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
            DDToolTip.AutomaticDelay = 5000;
            DDToolTip.ReshowDelay = 5000;

            InitDefaults();
        }

        public DDButton(DDButton btnLastButton)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DDToolTip = new ToolTip();
            DDToolTip.InitialDelay = 5000;
            DDToolTip.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
            DDToolTip.AutomaticDelay = 5000;
            DDToolTip.ReshowDelay = 5000;
            InitDefaults();
        }

...

protected override void OnMouseHover(EventArgs e)
        {
            Point pnt = new Point();
            pnt.X = this.Left + this.Size.Width + 10;
            pnt.Y = this.Bottom + 10;

            String strTooltip = "";

            try
            {
                strTooltip = strTooltip.Trim('\n');
                DDToolTip.Show(strTooltip, this.Parent, pnt, 10000);

                base.OnMouseHover(e);
                Capture = false;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
```

I expect for the ToolTip to display after hovering over a button for a specified amount of time as opposed to immediately displaying.

Comment: The delay you set are milliseconds. So 500ms is half a second. Are you sure that's what you intended?

Comment: I've set InitialDelay to 5000 (5 seconds), and it still appears immediately. I'll fix the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your OnMouseHover(EventArgs e) function.
All you need is:

```
toolTip1.AutoPopDelay = 5000;
toolTip1.InitialDelay = 1500;
toolTip1.AutomaticDelay = 1500;
toolTip1.ReshowDelay = 1500;

toolTip1.SetToolTip(myControl, "test");
```

If you use Show(), it will show immediately

Or you can always do something crazy like this:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    await Task.Delay(500);
    this.Invoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        toolTip1.Show("my text", myControl);
    }));
});
```

Comment: There's additional business logic that I didn't include in the example in the OnMouseHover function so I can't exactly remove that. Is there a way I can add a delay to the `Show()` instead?

Comment: yes you can, see my edit, but i would probably throttle that a bit

Comment: Thanks! That ended up working out the way I wanted it to. Appreciate the assistance.